# Making vertical text print specific way?

Tags: python, vertical-text

I'm writing a program for CS class and need help with some python 3 coding. This is my current code written:

```
def main():
    print() # blank line
    phrase = input("Please enter a phrase: ")
    wordlist = phrase.split()
    print("Original text:",phrase)
    for msg in wordlist:
        print(msg)
```

output:

```
    Phil
    likes
    to
    code
```

I can't use any imports or things like that. I can only use small things like loops or slices or split. Any help would be appreciated. I need the output to look like:

```
P l t c
h i o o
i k   d
l e   e
  s
```

Comment: so you got the first step you need to do ..... what do you think the next step should be ... I dont actually see any question here... I guess a hint would be you cant actually print things vertically(well you can but that starts getting very complicated using curses or something) ... only horizontally

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.zip_longest()` with fillvalue as space. Example -

```
>>> s = "Four score and seven years ago"
>>> ls = s.split()
>>> import itertools
>>> for i in itertools.zip_longest(*ls,fillvalue=' '):
...     print(*i)
...
F s a s y a
o c n e e g
u o d v a o
r r   e r
  e   n s
```

`itertools.izip_longest` for Python 2 .

Answer (score 0):

Without imports, as you asked:

```
words = phrase.split()
height = max(map(len, words))
padded = [word.ljust(height) for word in words]
for row in zip(*padded):
    print(' '.join(row))
```

I hope that's ok for you.

Comment: I wasn't able to use all the code you gave me but I was able to get an idea of it and make my code work correctly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: May I just ask why you weren't able to use the code above? (Moral or technical reasons?:)

Comment: Moral reasons. Couldn't use everything there because professor didn't show us yet